# How to close an Alexa skill that uses AudioPlayer interface

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently developing an Alexa skill where I use the `AudioPlayer` interface to play a song.

When the Cancel intent is called I do a :

```
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function() {
this.emit(':tell', "Bye!");}
```

The problem is that after alexa said "Bye", the audio is unpaused and the skill is still running.

How can I close the skill from an Intent handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send an `AudioPlayer.Stop` directive to stop any currently playing audio stream.

```
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function() {
   this.response.speak('Bye').audioPlayerStop();
   this.emit(':responseReady');
}
```

In ask-sdk-v2 you can use:

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .addAudioPlayerStopDirective()
      .getResponse();
```

**Update**
Alexa service will track your audio player skill as the skill that most recently streamed audio and for any built in intent, Alexa will create a new session and trigger the request to your skill.

> When your skill sends a Play directive to begin playback, the Alexa service sends the audio stream to the device for playback.
>   Once the session ends normally (for instance, if your response
>   included the shouldEndSession flag set to true), Alexa remembers that
>   your skill started the playback until the user does one of the
>   following:
>
> 1. Invokes audio playback with a different skill.
> 2. Invokes another service that streams audio, such as the built-in music service or the flash briefing.
> 3. Reboots the device.

Check this documentation [Built-in Intents for Playback Control](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#intents)

More on AudioPlayer directives [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html)

Comment: The audio is paused with this but the skill is still running, what i want is the skill to be closed after this intent has benn called. Thank you for your quick reply anyway